# get all parents of a child in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have location table. All the locations are stored in this table along their

```
  ID,Title and Parent_ID
```

I need to get all the parents of a single ID until a child has no parent. A vague idea in my mind is of course self join. But, how would i do this?

PS: Sorry for poor explanation.

Comment: Did none of the questions that are listed under the "Related" title in the right column help?

Comment: how does 1 child have multiple parents?

Comment: i meant in hierarchical sense. like a child has a parent and that parent is child of some parent and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
SELECT
  T2.*
FROM (
       SELECT
         @r               AS _id,
         (SELECT @r := parent_id
          FROM REQUIRED_TABLE
          WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id
       FROM
         (SELECT
            @r := REQUIRED_ID) vars,
         REQUIRED_TABLE m
       WHERE @r <> 0) T1
  JOIN yii2_jobs T2
    ON T1.parent_id = T2.id;
```

ORIGINAL_UNIT_ID it is unit id. REQUIRED_TABLE it is table name. You need replace this. More information you can find here https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/